# How to calculate IVs properly

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been using different IV raters and calculator in web and application. And mose of them require to put the informacion about CP, HP and dust needed for power up. However, some of them also require to put your trainer level like the following:

https://thesilphroad.com/research

Does this mean whenever i check the IV of a pokemon what matters is the level of when i catched it? Or my current level?

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per Chris' comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current level. Because the max CP of a pokemon is a product of your current level times a multiplier.

See: https://gist.github.com/KazWolfe/68e10ebf1ed41ae1ae6de2350d5de884 line:574

Answer (score 2):

Once caught a pokemon's IV will never change. The reason your trainer level may make a difference is that the pokemon's level is limited by your trainer level. When working out IVs it is something of a trial and error effort so knowing the upper limit of the possible pokemon level by knowing your trainer level can help them narrow down your pokemon's stats.